# Write spark dataframe to postgres Database

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

The spark cluster setting is as follows:

```
conf['SparkConfiguration'] = SparkConf() \
.setMaster('yarn-client') \
.setAppName("test") \
.set("spark.executor.memory", "20g") \
.set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "20g") \
.set("spark.executor.instances", "20")\
.set("spark.executor.cores", "3") \
.set("spark.memory.fraction", "0.2") \
.set("user", "test_user") \
.set("spark.executor.extraClassPath", "/usr/share/java/postgresql-jdbc3.jar")
```

When I try to write the dataframe to the Postgres DB using the following code:

```
from pyspark.sql import DataFrameWriter
my_writer = DataFrameWriter(df)

url_connect = "jdbc:postgresql://198.123.43.24:1234"
table = "test_result"
mode = "overwrite"
properties = {"user":"postgres", "password":"password"}

my_writer.jdbc(url_connect, table, mode, properties)
```

I encounter the below error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1120.jdbc.   
:java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:278)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$2.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:50)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$2.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:50)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.createConnectionFactory(JdbcUtils.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.jdbc(DataFrameWriter.scala:278)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Can anyone provide some suggestions on this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

Try write.jdbc and pass the parameters individually created outside the write.jdbc(). 
Also check the port on which postgres is available for writing mine is 5432 for Postgres 9.6 and 5433 for Postgres 8.4.

```
mode = "overwrite"
url = "jdbc:postgresql://198.123.43.24:5432/kockpit"
properties = {"user": "postgres","password": "password","driver": "org.postgresql.Driver"}
data.write.jdbc(url=url, table="test_result", mode=mode, properties=properties)
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you downloaded the PostgreSQL JDBC Driver? Download it here: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html.

For the pyspark shell you use the SPARK_CLASSPATH environment variable:

```
$ export SPARK_CLASSPATH=/path/to/downloaded/jar
$ pyspark
```

For submitting a script via spark-submit use the --driver-class-path flag:

```
$ spark-submit --driver-class-path /path/to/downloaded/jar script.py
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try passing the JDBC driver class explicitly (Note that you may need to put the driver jar in the classpath for all spark nodes):

```
df.write.option('driver', 'org.postgresql.Driver').jdbc(url_connect, table, mode, properties)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It gives the below error message: TypeError: 'DataFrameWriter' object is not callable

Comment: @Yiliang, sorry, in pyspark `write` is not a function, you should do `df.write` instead of `df.write()`. My mistake

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Now I encounter java.lang.NullPointerException for that line. Any idea what could go wrong?