# Write to Postgres from Databricks using Python

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a dataframe in Databricks called customerDetails.

```
+--------------------+-----------+
|        customerName| customerId|
+--------------------+-----------+
|John Smith          |       0001|
|Jane Burns          |       0002|
|Frank Jones         |       0003|
+--------------------+-----------+
```

I would like to be able to copy this from Databricks to a table within Postgres.

I found this [post](https://www.lewuathe.com/python/postgresql/remind-for-insert-into-with-psycopg2.html) which used psycopg2 to copy individual lines to Postgres, I am trying to copy each row from the dataframe to the postgres table?

```
import psycopg2

v1 = 'testing_name'
v2 = 'testing_id'


conn = psycopg2.connect(host="HOST_NAME",
                        port="PORT",
                        user="USER_NAME",
                        password="PASSWORD",
                        database="DATABASE_NAME")

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO customerTable (customerName, customerId) VALUES(%s, %s)", (v1, v2))
conn.commit()
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert, row by row, all the data into your table.

See the documentation for [cursor.executemany](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.executemany) too as you can reorder your data as a list of tuples and pass the list as the last argument.

The code will be almost identical to the example you gave

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
def append_to_table(row):
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO customerTable (customerName, customerId) VALUES(%s, %s)", (row.customerName, row.customerId))

df.rdd.map(append_to_table)
conn.commit()
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried this and received an error:  'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'

Comment: oops, try using the `rdd` conversion

Comment: Thanks. It runs without an error now, only it it doesn't seem to actually copy anything  to the table.

Comment: hmm, try printing out the `row.customerName` to make sure it's actually running through each row

Comment: it doesn't seem to be printing anything.

Comment: hmm, try using `df.foreach` instead of `map`, see [the docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.foreach)

Comment: Not sure this will work as you surely need a separate connection/cursor object on each partition? If that is the case, you could modify the code to create a connection per partition, write all the data in the partition and then kill the connection, using mapPartition.

Comment: alternatively, you can try a built-in method like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38825836/write-spark-dataframe-to-postgres-database)